# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError when running staging DB on local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, aes

I just copied our staging server database into my development, and now I receive this error whenever I load any data

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError
```

Which occurs at the following piece of code

```
credentials = encrypted_credentials.inject({}) do |hash, (key, value)|
   hash[key] = AESCrypt.decrypt(value, password) <-----------
   hash
end
```

Anybody have a clue why this is?

Answer (score 14):

Turned out I was using the wrong encryption password, because it was stored in a environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I (mostly) followed the instructions here: https://myrtana.sk/articles/howto-fix-rails-7-openssl-cipher-error

Steps:

- Removed `credentials.yml`
- Created new credentials file using VS Code `EDITOR='code --w' bin/rails credentials:edit`