# Ruby On Rails - "OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError at ..." when connecting to imported database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am running my Ruby On Rails 5 app on localhost and now, I imported the production database. It's a PostgreSQL database, exported via the `pg_dump` tool.

When I modified the `database.yml` file the Rails app and set there the newly created database, I got this error when running the Rails app (tried also to change the port on which the app is running, but it didn't help):

```
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError at /
```

[image]

In the Rails console is not any information about the error.

What is the reason of such an error? I tried to export the database from the staging server and use it on localhost and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-final

It looks like you don't have the proper encryption key to connect to the production db.

I would guess you either do have the proper one for staging, or staging is running unencrypted.

Here's someone else with the same error caused by an incorrect key: [OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError when running staging DB on local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311946/opensslcipherciphererror-when-running-staging-db-on-local)